# Getting the absolute value of a counter

Tags: counters

I'm trying to get the absolute value of a counter, but couldn't find anything online and can't seem to come up with a solution myself.
The goal is not to get absolute value symbols (there is plenty to find for that), but the actual value, like `Math.abs(-1)` in JS.

[image: depiction of the goal (in JS)]

Has anyone an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When TeX wants to process `\number`, it does macro expansion; so we can add a minus sign when the counter's value is negative.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\absolutearabic}[1]{%
  \number\ifnum\value{#1}<0 -\fi\value{#1}%
}

\newcounter{test}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{test}{2}
\absolutearabic{test}

\setcounter{test}{-3}
\absolutearabic{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's the perfect solution for my case!

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches: string processing using `xstring` to remove any `-` characters, or proper calculation using `abs()` from `xfp`. Both also work in case the counter is positive.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{xfp}
\newcounter{negcnt}
\setcounter{negcnt}{-5}
\begin{document}
counter: \thenegcnt

abs xstring: \StrDel{\thenegcnt}{-}

abs xfp: \fpeval{abs(\value{negcnt})}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]